# can I return this: context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>()?

Tags: c#

I added a class called Connect.cs;

```
namespace MovieApp.DAL
{
   public class Connect
   {
      public Connection()  //my class needs to have a return type
      {
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"];
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext(connStr.ConnectionString);
        var movieContext = context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>();
        return movieContext;
      }
   }
}
```

then i have in my controller class:

```
namespace MovieApp.Controllers
{
    public class MovieController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
       {
        Connect connection = new Connect(//and what will i put here??);
        var movies = connection.OrderBy(m => m.Title);
        return View(movies);
        }
}
```

obviously i get errors because I do not know how to do this.
Of what type will movieContext be?
How do I get this code to work please?
thanks!

Comment: what type does `context.CreateObjectSet<T>()` return? Use that type for `public xxxxx Connection()` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public ObjectSet<Movie> Connection()
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"];
    ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext(connStr.ConnectionString);
    var movieContext = context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>();
    return movieContext;
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Connect connection = new Connect();
    var movies = connection.Connection().OrderBy(m => m.Title);
    return View(movies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Connection" method's return type should be the return type of "`context.CreateObjectSet<Movie>()`" method call; which is `ObjectSet<Movie>`

Comment: quite right thanks, havent done this in three years so very rusty but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you didn't specify the return type of the `Connection` method. I.e. `public Connection()` should be `public ObjectSet<T> Connection<T>()`.

You can try something like this (code written in notepad so it is just to demonstrate the idea)

```
public class ObjectContextManager
{
    public ObjectSet GetSet<T>()  
    {
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"];
        ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext(connStr.ConnectionString);
        return context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}
```

And then you inject the manager into controller and resolve the needed set from there. Don't forget to wrap the database object into a `using` block so `Dispose` is automatically called.

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    private ObjectContextManager ctxManager;

    public MovieController(ObjectContextManager ctxManager)
    {
        this.ctxManager = ctxManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using(var ctx = ctxManager.GetSet<Movie>())
        {
            var movies = ctx.OrderBy(m => m.Title);
            return View(movies);
        }
    }
}
```